# Wordpress page loading errors - 404 undefinedpageWebRequest.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm suddenly getting a 404 error on the file undefinedpageWebRequest.js file my website tries to load. I have no idea what the .js is for, why the 404 is showing up (I didn't delete any files from FTP?) and I also can't find anything about the file on Google.

[image: Safari concole]

Also when I run my page through Google Mobile tool I get about 6 errors. How can I go around and fix this? I have no idea where to begin in the first place.
https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?hl=nl&id=FjRctNhGZy3ybi6o1aAmug&view=fetch-info

Website URL: www.melvinosenga.nl/home

Comment: Well, if you don't know why/what JS files you are using, it is weird.

Comment: I do not see any 404 on that webpage though.

Comment: @BerenddeGroot Which browser are you on?

Comment: I tested it in both chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .js file your webpage is loading is the following one:
https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js

And I guess it is a requirement for a plugin you have installed in your Wordpress site, which is most likely dead.

If you are not using the plugin you should uninstall it, and if it doesn't work you can search for the line where it is called in the headers and remove it by-hand(not very neat, I would do this as a last option).

In the other errors you have there is a Image error and some missing fonts, you should check that and refill the fonts that are missing.

Let me know if I can help you in any of this procedures.